# Browser addon to save entered form fields on specific form

Tags: browser-addons, forms

I tried several browser addons for various browsers and can't find simple addon that will remember filled form when I click on some button, and later restore it on the same page on some another button click.

To clarify I am developing web application with pretty complicated forms, and when testing it's tedious and boring enter all that data so many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lazarus: Form Recovery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno), a chrome extension.

> **Autosaves everything you type so you can easily recover from
>   form-killing timeouts, crashes and network errors.**
>
> Ever had one of
>   those “oh $*#@” moments when you've finally finished filling out a
>   long form, and hit submit only to see an error message? And when you
>   hit the back button, the form was blank... If so, you know you need
>   Lazarus. And if not, you have a chance to install Lazarus before
>   disaster strikes!
>
> Lazarus saves everything you type so if the worst happens you can
>   recover the whole form by simply clicking a menu item. The data can be
>   encrypted and is saved on your machine so you know it's safe.

Similar extension is also available for firefox.

Comment: I tried Lazarus before and for some reason it doesn't save my form, maybe becouse it has a 3 pages and 3 submits

Comment: You should mention that in your questions. When you submit question, please mention what have you tried already. It saves all troubles

Comment: sorry, you are right, my apologies. But I tried only in Firefox, now I installed Lazarus in Chrome and it works ! Thanks